# Push notification WIndows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

### Push notification WIndows Phone 8

i am developing windows phone 8 application using c#/xaml. i have to implement push notification. I got example from *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970(v=vs.105).aspx*. I follwed all the steps they have mentioned. But the bachkground image is not getting updated. How should i specify background image uri from server?

Answer (score 2):

Did you include the images as Assets to your WP8 Project, and did you change the Build Action of the images from properties to Content.

Because I followed the same project, and I can receive tile notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got it worked.The channel uri was the problem,it has got updated on adding new domain.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this i am facing same problem?